# Appcelerator - include jar in build at compile-time?

Tags: jar, appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop, hyperloop, appc-hyperloop

Since Appcelerator(/Hyperloop) doesn't use Gradle or Maven to manage dependencies, I need to include them all manually for my project by placing them in the app/platform/android folder. I have done this, however I also need to include google dagger (https://github.com/google/dagger) which requires including dagger-compiler-2.x.jar , which I believe is an annotation processor that generates some type of code during compile-time.

Simply placing this in the app/platform/android folder like any other jar results in this error when the dexer is running during the build:

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  PARSE ERROR:
[ERROR] :  MethodHandle not supported
[ERROR] :  ...while preparsing cst 016c at offset 00001ceb
[ERROR] :  ...while parsing com/google/googlejavaformat/java/JavaInput.class
[ERROR] :  1 error; aborting
```

I think it has something to do with the part of the dagger instructions which state "you will need to include dagger-compiler-2.x.jar in your build at compile time." Is there somewhere else that I need to place this jar file to get it to be used properly? Or is the use of compile-time annotation processors not something that Appcelerator/Hyperloop supports at this time? Any thoughts or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A good amount has changed since this question was asked.  This being said, I believe that currently Hyperloop for Android doesn't handle annotations.  And this is how dependency injection systems work, so I believe it's still not currently possible to use that or similar JARs.